# Would social network activity with links pointing to my website be considered a link scheme?

Tags: seo, google

Are tweets and Facebook shares/likes of posts with links to my site considered a link scheme? Especially when the tweeting and sharing of the link is encouraged with prizes?

Would this get me banned from Google? To be honest  I am more interested in the awareness of the site from friends and do not need much traffic or traffic from Google itself. Still, I would not want to mess up the reputation of the site on the internet by being banned from Google!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All links posted via Facebook shares or Twitter Tweets are *rel="nofollow"*. So these links should have no impact on your rankings in Google (as well as other major search engines) regardless.

Google has extra information on what they consider a *Link Scheme* to be here - [Google: Link schemes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en)